# How to describe wearing a T-shirt in a opposite manner?

Tags: word-request

Let's say I put on a T-shirt with back in front and front in back. Is there any word to describe the state of the t-short similar to how **upside down** means that up and down have been reversed?. The sentence where I am trying to use it is something like this:

> First the I wore the T-shirt the right way round. Then I put it on […].

Additionally, if my friend does the same thing (i.e. wearing the T-shirt in the reverse manner), and I want to tell him to fix it. Can I say "Take it off and reverse it"?

Does *reverse* make sense in this context?

Comment: If I recall it correctly, my friend told me "your shirt is front back."

Comment: @kiamlaluno He probably said "your shirt is front-*to*-back". That's not how I say it personally, but I've heard it; it's common enough :) (I think some people also say back-to-front; this might be more British? But I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @WendiKidd: "Back-to-front" is perfectly normal idiomatic English ("front-to-back" less so). In US English, it's more common to say "Backwards".

Comment: @Matt, I think you have it backwards; in *my* experience, “front-to-back” is common idiomatic English, and “back-to-front” sounds completely wrong.

Comment: @jwpat7: Not in British English: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back-to-front%2Cfront-to-back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=. In American English "front-to-back" is more popular: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back-to-front%2Cfront-to-back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=. Actually see FumbleFinger's answer. He got there first :)

Comment: Front-to-back *can* mean backwards, but it doesn't *usually*, so I'm afraid the n-gram results aren't meaningful in this context.

Comment: @snailboat: Further investigation suggests you're right. I just assumed *front-to-back* was the US version because of what Wenndikidd said, which seemed to be corroborated by my NGrams on US/UK corpora. But when I specifically search for *"[potentially reversible item of clothing] on front-to-back"* it virtually *never* occurs, whereas there are plenty of results for things like ["shirt on back-to-front"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shirt+on+back-to-front%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I don't know what context accounts for all the US *front-to-back* hits, but it ain't clothes!

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Reading](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+front+to+back&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3), I suspect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two common words to describe putting a shirt on wrong.

In the situation you describe, when the front of the shirt is on the person's back, I'd refer to it as *backwards*:

> You've got your shirt on backwards!

If you put it on when it was inverted, that is the inside of the shirt is showing on the outside, I'd call that *inside-out*.

> Your shirt is on inside-out!

I'm having trouble thinking of an idiomatic way to tell the person to take the shirt off and fix it, though; likely because *"Your shirt's on backwards!"* is usually sufficient to get someone to fix the error themselves. But I think this would work as a good description:

> You've got your shirt on backwards! Take it off and flip it around.

That is, turn the front of the shirt to the front of your body, fixing the mistake.

*Reverse* is understandable, it just doesn't roll off the tongue very easily here. I'd stick with *turn it around/flip it around*.

Comment: And then there's "inside-out and backwards." In that case, I'd probably begin with, "Whoa! That must've been some party last night..." :^)

Answer (score 8):

The most common term overall is probably *backwards*, as noted by WendiKidd. But I've only just discovered that the standard alternative [in the **US** is **front-to-back**...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back-to-front,front-to-back&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
[image]

To my British ear that version sounds odd, because [in the **UK** it's **back-to-front**...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back-to-front,front-to-back&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)
[image]

You wouldn't normally use the word *reverse* except when talking about something like a [reversible jacket](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reversible%20jacket%20pictures&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=zWQiUvznCsfg7QaRgoHwBA&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1480&bih=922). And [inside-out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inside+out) is a completely different type of "reversal" (with the [*lining*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lining) on the *outside*, rather than the *front* at the *back*).

Personally, I'd tell someone to *"put it [on] the right way [round]"* for *any* a back-to-front or an inside-out garment. I might include *on* and/or *round* on any given occasion, but I don't think that would be affected by whether it was a shirt, gloves, pants, or whatever.

Another point which may be purely personal is that I'd normally use *back-to-front* in contexts where it's a ***mistake***. If someone is deliberately wearing a baseball cap *backwards*, that's how I tend to describe it. Unless I'm irritated by it, in which case I might say *back-to-front* to indicate that ***I*** think it's a "mistake".

Comment: Ah, you decorous Brits! Most people I know just say "Yer shirt's bass-ackward" or "Yer shirt's ****ed. Fix it."

Comment: @StoneyB: In certain contexts I might say something's *arse-about-face*, which is at least the same way round as *back-to-front*, so to speak. I can't believe Americans would say *face-about-ass*, so there's something not quite right there. I'd also note that Brits can fall *arse over tit*, but I doubt anyone (even Americans) would fall *tit over ass*.

Comment: I'm not sure what these Ngrams have to do with the O.P.'s question. I've never heard anyone say "You've got your shirt on front-to-back," but I've seen "front-to-back" used in plenty of other contexts, such as sewing, stretching, antennae, and a host of others as well. Paging through the results, I was able to find more than one reference where _front-to-back_ was used as a way to  prevent urinary tract infections, but I couldn't find one where it was describing someone's misdonned jersey. Maybe some do say it, but I'm afraid these Ngrams don't really say much about this matter.

Comment: @J.R.: Per my most recent comment to the question itself, I'm no longer sure myself why Google Books apparently shows a marked US/UK split between *front-to-back/back-to-front*, since (Wendikidd excepted) it doesn't seem at all common for Americans to use *front-to-back* in respect of abnormal fore/aft orientation. In most other contexts it just sounds totally redundant to me. Why would anyone say they comb their hair front-to-back, for example? I'd just comb mine *back*.

Comment: @Fumble - I think _front-to-back_ is used in more procedural contexts. In other words, I just comb my hair back, but, while training an intern at a salon, you might hear a stylist tell the trainee: "You want to comb the hair from front to back."

Comment: @J.R.: Yes, but I very specifically charted the *hyphenated* versions. NGrams helpfully adds a space before and after every hyphen (saying that's how they indexed the text in the first place). For some reason that prevents me *looking at* the results, but I assume NGrams does actually *work*, so Americans really are using hyphenated *front-to-back* more than *back-to-front*. But regardless of which way round the *words* go, I can't imagine many people (UK or US) hyphenating something like *comb the hair from front-to-back*. It's all very mysterious, and I for one would like to know more.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That's what you _tried_ to do, but, unless I can see the results, I don't assume Ngrams gets it right. [See this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+the+get+go&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Notice there's _no_ hyphen. Now, [see the results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22from%20the%20get%20go%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:1997&lr=lang_en); they are littered with hyphens. The software just isn't that good. I wanted to know more, too; I started with [this](http://www.google.com/#q=%22and+front-to-back%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Comment: @J.R.: I know Google comes out with some real howlers. Just now I pointed out that [**estimated** 30,100,000 results leads to 22 **actual** results](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124990/) on ELU. I know why that is (guesses are based on the prevalence of individual words and subsections within the search text). But I can't think of any reason why in our current case it should show such a marked US/UK divide - a point which you don't seem to be addressing at all.

Comment: @Fumble - Oh, don't get me wrong, I found that _front-to-back in the US, back-to-front in the UK_ finding very odd, interesting, and worth pointing out. I only meant to say that, whatever the reason for that anomaly, it has nothing to do with how I tell someone that they have put their shirt on backwards. On a different question (such as, "When talking about a repeated motion, like that of a pendulum, should I say 'front-to-back', or 'back-to-front'?"), your finding may have been more pertinent.

Comment: @J.R.: To me, the hyphenated versions (only one of which I'm familiar with) are nothing to do with repeated motions, direction of travel, or anything like that. In *my* English *back-to-front* means *the wrong way round, on the fore/aft axis*. I can't think of any contexts where it could ever mean anything else and still have hyphens.

Comment: @Fumble: As I said, your comments were very curious, so I did some investigating on my own. Sometimes hyphens _are_ used when describing such a motion: see [Exhibit A](http://books.google.com/books?id=i-tOkSSeUyAC&pg=PA28&dq=stickhandling+hockey+%22front+to+back%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7gQlUqesOcuxsQSirYCwBQ&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=stickhandling%20hockey%20%22front%20to%20back%22&f=false).

Comment: Also, see [Exhibit B](http://books.google.com/books?id=GLfu3tR9x0EC&pg=PT180&dq=wipe+front-to-back&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQUlUpDbFfOO2gXD-IGYBw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=wipe%20front-to-back&f=false). Looking at Exhibit B, I must say, I was _really_ hoping I wouldn't have to relive this, and that you would just take my word for it. ;^) As I said earlier: "sewing, stretching, antennae, and .. more than one reference where _front-to-back_ was used as a way to prevent urinary tract infections..."

Comment: [Exhibit C](http://books.google.com/books?id=1yTK1TwsV-kC&pg=PA92&dq=stretching+%22front-to-back%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kAYlUr_GJojH2QWxgoGgCQ&ved=0CHIQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=stretching%20%22front-to-back%22&f=false) is _stretching_, like a gymnast or yoga practitioner might do. I would have embedded links the first time around, but they are just too long to fit in these comments.

Comment: @J.R.: Actually, I more or less *do* have to take your word for it - your links just take me to the relevant GB "sales" pages for the books. (But having noticed the word "wipe" in the search term for the second link, I'm actually quite glad not to have my nose rubbed in the full text! :)

Comment: @Fumble - Ah, very well, my good friend – [seeing is believing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iQbsO.png).

Comment: @J.R.: Okay, I made some over-hasty generalisations earlier. Those three are "unexceptional" usages to me as well. But we're still faced with that apparent US/UK split, which I only charted in the first place because of comments by Wendikidd and jwpat. I don't see any reason why the "unexceptional" usages should be any more common in the US than the UK, so presumably *something* must account for what we seem to be seeing in the charts.

Answer (score 5):

To me "reverse it" would more likely be inside out (that is, with the part that usually touches your body showing and the part that is usually exterior touching your body).

For what you want, I would say "back-to-front".